# Efficient use of a pedal generator

Tags: batteries, charging

Using a 90 amp alternator on a pedal generator how many 12 volt batteries can be efficiently charged at the same time? Thanks

Comment: A human  can put out almost 400 watts by petal generator.

Comment: @tuskiomi: a typical human can put out 400 watts with a *pedal generator for maybe 2 seconds, many will struggle just getting to 100W.

Comment: Somewhere around 500W for an hour is possible - for Graeme Obree or Chris Boardman.

Comment: a fit but untrained 80kg man can climb stairs at about 3 seconds per floor, floors being about 3m apart and gravity being about \$ 10kgm/s^2 \$ that's about 800W, but after climbing 10 floors in 30 seconds there's not much energy left.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it may take 40W simply to energise the alternator. If you're producing a more realistic 120W rather than a seriously athletic 400W Tour de France performance, that leaves only 2/3 of your output (80W, about 6A) for charging batteries.

How many batteries can you charge at once? That depends on the battery. If you take a common 90Ah leisure battery, one. And you can fully charge it in only about 15 hours of pedalling.